# Why can't the PAB webserver find a socket in PAB-Nami demo?

Tags: cabal, plutus-pab, pab, nix-shell

I'm trying to run the [PAB-Nami simple demo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables/demo/pab-nami#pab-nami-simple-demo) in the Plutus Apps repo. When I run the PAB, either using `cabal` or with the `nix-shell` script, I'm getting the error:

```
plutus-pab-nami-demo: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 18>: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong, and there is no mention of configuring the socket in the README.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Start up a Cardano Node.

Also, make sure to set the node socket path to to location of your node.sock file is:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/cardano-node/example/socket/
```

Comment: It would make sense if it was looking for a Cardano Node, but the instructions specifically say, "It doesn't use a local Cardano node, nor the chain index." I might try it anyway.

Comment: I just needed to spin up a Cardano Node. Thanks.

Comment: I want to award you the answer, but we should probably only include the Cardano Node in the answer. The index and wallet aren't necessary, and it doesn't use the socket path env var.

Comment: I revised my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The node socket  env var isn't used AFAICT. It uses the `pscSocketPath` value in `plutus-pab-executables/demo/pab-nami/pab/plutus-pab.yaml`. I actually have an PR up on the repo to fix the instructions:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/pull/362

Comment: Although my answer helped you along, it seems like you've discovered the actual solution.  I'm not sure the best way to make the changes on this post.  I think I'll leave as-is for now.

Comment: Cool. I'll add an answer once my PR goes through, I guess. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed a Cardano Node running and I needed to point at the socket. To point your PAB at the socket, update the `pscSocketPath` value in `plutus-pab-executables/demo/pab-nami/pab/plutus-pab.yaml`. I got node running following the instructions [here](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/).

Comment: I created a PR to update the docs to include this information. That has been merged.